# Blender 2.8 Shader editor : I can't add any node

Tags: shaders

[image]

As you See on Photo I cant add something on shader editor. What am i supposted to do?

Comment: Click on "New" in the middle of the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a material by clicking on the NEW button in the Shader Editor header.

[image]

Comment: oh Thank you so much. Im new to blender :). problem solved. Im so grateful.